# Change image src and id when image is clicked (Play / Pause button)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a play / pause button.
This is what I have right now.
Here is the html.

```
<img alt="play" src="img/play.png" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="position: relative; width: 10%; z-index: 10000; margin: 0 auto; top: 42%;"/>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function changeImage() {

    if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "../final_copy/img/play.png") 
    {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "../final_copy/img/pause.png";
    }
    else {
        if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "../final_copy/img/pause.png")
            {
             document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "../final_copy/img/play.png";
            }
        }
}
```

I know th second "if" probably isn't needed but neither way works.  I can only get the image to change from the play image to the pause image but when I click it again it doesn't change back.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the `if` condition, you need to use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Ok, So I tried all of the code everyone provided and none of them worked, I still get the same problem.  I can switch from the play to the pause button but not back to the play button.  Thank you everyone  for the help so far, hopefully this is an easy fix!

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing those src values wrong. Use `==` instead of `=`

```
if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "../final_copy/img/play.png") {
     document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "../final_copy/img/pause.png";
}
else {
 if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "../final_copy/img/pause.png") {
     document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "../final_copy/img/play.png";
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok, So I tried all of the code everyone provided and none of them worked, I still get the same problem. I can switch from the play to the pause button but not back to the play button. Thank you everyone for the help so far, hopefully this is an easy fix!

Comment: Sure no prob! Glad to help! If you want for us to look your updated code, you can ask.

Answer (score 3):

If its a simple toggle function, you'd need just one check:

```
function changeImage() {
  if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "../final_copy/img/play.png") {
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "../final_copy/img/pause.png";
    }else{  
        document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "../final_copy/img/play.png";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need var isPasued=false; switch image src!

```
var isPaused=false;
var imgObj=document.querySelect("img")[0];  //edit this
imgObj.addEventListener("click",function(){
     if(!isPaused){
         imgObj.src="../final_copy/img/play.png";
         isPaused=true;
     }
     else
     {
         imgObj.src="../final_copy/img/pause.png";
         isPaused=false;
     }
});
```

= is == I agree the one answer in up!

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = "document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src",
    play = "../final_copy/img/play.png",
    pause = "../final_copy/img/pause.png";

if (element == play) {
    element = pause;
} else {
    if (element == pause) {
        element = play";
    }
}
}
```